# Writing to .innerHTML doesn't work when served from webserver but works when browsed as a file, what could be causing this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I'm using mootool's Request.JSON to retrieve tweets from Twitter.
After I receive it, I write to the .innerHTML property for my target div.
When I test this locally as a file, i.e. file:// is in the URL, I see my formatted tweets on the webpage.
When I serve this from my local webserver, i.e. http://, the formatted tweets are not showing up in my div.

What could be causing this? (I've tested this in Safari and Chrome on OSX...same behavior)
I've included the code that's from the HEAD section of my page.
Also, when I debug the Javascript in Safari:

"TypeError: Result of expression 'data' [undefined] is not an object" appears for the onComplete callback function declaration.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-1.3-full-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitterjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/twitter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jSonRequest = new Request.JSON(
    {
        url:'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=+nytimes+OR+TheEconomist',
        onSuccess: function(data) {
            var target = document.getElementById('twitter_content');
            target.innerHTML = ''; //clear the contents
            for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length ; i++) {
                var tweet = data.results[i];

                //process it and add html for hashtags and links
                var processed_tweet_text = tweet.text;

                //process HTTP urls first...otherwise we would get the added links for the hashtags
                var twre = /(http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.\/]+)/ig
                processed_tweet_text = processed_tweet_text.replace( twre, '<a href="$1">$1</a>' );

                //process hashtags and add link
                twre = /\@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/ig; //match twitter accounts starting with @ and includes and of these characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, "_" and "-" characters.
                processed_tweet_text = processed_tweet_text.replace( twre, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>' );

                target.innerHTML += '<div class="tweet"><a href="http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '">' + '<img src="' + tweet.profile_image_url + '"><div class="tweet_text"><div class="tweet_user"><a href="http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '">' + tweet.from_user + '</a></div><div class="tweet_message">' + processed_tweet_text + '</div></div></div>';
                //console.log(tweet.from_user); 
            }
        }
    }).send();
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

OK. So I've found two answers...one with mootools and one with jQuery...thanks to everyone's suggestions.

For mootools, *make sure you get the "more" .js file with the Request.JSONP class* http://mootools.net/more/
(I was pulling my hair out because I was getting a constructor error...and I finally realized that I didn't have the Request.JSONP class!!!)

Then just change code to this:

```
var jSonRequest = new Request.JSONP(
{...
```

For JQuery:

```
//adding callback=? forces a JSONP call...so no issues with AJAX cross-domain requests  
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=+nytimes+OR+TheEconomist&callback=?",
  function(data) {...
```

Comment: I would guess it's because you're making a cross-domain ajax call and so you're getting no data from the call.

Comment: MooTools (and jQuery, which you've also included) provides JSONP for this. JSONP in MooTools: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP, in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp

Comment: @eyelidlessness - I want to give you the "check mark" for the correct answer so can you move your comment to an answer?  :)

Comment: `JSON` is not cross-domain. Use `JSONP` instead.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?

example class that i wrote that extends Request.JSONP for twitter access:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/WxzZ5/33/

Comment: @Dimitar - that's pretty awesome.

Comment: @milesmeow, that's alright, climbage's answer came in while I was typing the comment (because I went to look up the documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `new Request.JSONP` instead of `new Request.JSON`.

Comment: Just that simple substitution didn't work. I'll look at the docs for JSONP and try to figure it out.

Comment: @milesmeow, yeah that doesn't surprise me, but you get the idea.

Comment: you were totally right. It was not working because I didn't have the mootools "more" library...I created one here http://mootools.net/more/, included the .js file and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to decode the data

```
var object = JSON.decode(data);
```

You can read this [document](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/JSON)

this is a sample

```
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url: 'http://somesite.com/tellMeAge.php',
    onSuccess: function(person){
        alert(person.age);    // alerts "25 years".
    }
})
```

look onSuccess not onComplete

Comment: It works locally without the decode, but when I add the decode it doesn't work at all...so I don't think it's because of the decode.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, got that...saw in the documentation that I need to us onSuccess. Still didn't solve the issue. I'll keep trying, but I don't think it's a decode issue.